# Certbot generate cert automatically on Ubuntu 16.04 with XAMPP

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, certbot

I met the case I could not do the same logic by '--apachectl',
and certbot said it is depreciated, then I found the version is not latest on 16.04,
and I cannot upgrade the OS to 18.04, so I have to try another way to do generate cert automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the case and would like to share here for someone if it is helpful.

### XAMPP Virtual Host on my case

#### Webroot Path

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com/
```

#### Virtual Host Config

```
/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot  "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com"
ServerName abcd.com
<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com/domain_error_log"
ErrorDocument 404 '404'
</VirtualHost>
```

#### .Well-Known

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com/.well-known/acme-challenge
```

### 1. Important Steps when we will use --manual-auth-hook --manual-cleanup-hook by creating execute file(.sh)

#### 1.1 Create authenticator.sh

```
sudo nano /opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com.authenticator.sh
#----- copy and paste -----
#!/bin/bash
echo $CERTBOT_VALIDATION > /opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/vtl-solutions.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/$CERTBOT_TOKEN
#----- copy and paste -----

sudo chmod -R 777  /opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com.authenticator.sh
```

#### 1.2 Create cleanup.sh

```
sudo nano /opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com.cleanup.sh
#----- copy and paste -----
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/$CERTBOT_TOKEN
#----- copy and paste -----

sudo chmod -R 777  /opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com.cleanup.sh
```

### 2. We can run command to do now

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual \
 --preferred-challenges=http \
 --manual-auth-hook /opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com.authenticator.sh \
 --manual-cleanup-hook /opt/lampp/htdocs/abcd.com.cleanup.sh \
 -d abcd.com
```

And here is a detail and execute log for reference:

https://github.com/oliguo/Server-Certbot-XAMPP-Ubuntu